# Using theme inherited from Theme.Dialog for an activity, the content in the root layout always move down about 30dp

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I used a custom theme for my activity.  This theme was inherited from Theme.Dialog.

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>

</style>
```

The root layout of this activity's view is LinearLayout.  The problem is: the content in the root layout always move down about 30dp ON ANDROID 4.0, but works well ON ANDROID 2.2.  I don't know why.  I searched for hours, and found that maybe this line is solution:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

I wrote this line in my OnCreate(), but still can't solve this problem.
If you know why, please tell me.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by using below code

when your creating dialog pass the theeme as follows

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,
            android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```

hope it will solve your problem